# UIWebView and NSURLCache issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I am trying to utilize the `NSURLCache` when loading a link in `UIWebView`. Inside the `UIWebView` I have a bunch of links of images and I want to cache this so I can utilize this later. How do I do this? I have set the `NSURLSharedCache` size.

EDIT:

I am doing a `loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL` to load the content into the `UIWebView`, maybe that's why it's not calling in, right?

Comment: So what exactly is going wrong? I can't tell...is it that it isn't getting cached or is the `loadHTMLString:...` call just plain failing?

Comment: the issue is that it isn't getting cached..

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting disk cache, rather than memory cache, then you should take a look at SDURLCache:
https://github.com/steipete/SDURLCache

From the README:

> On iPhone OS, Apple did remove on-disk cache support for unknown
>   reason. Some will say it's to save flash-drive life, others will arg
>   it's to save disk capacity. As it is explained in the
>   NSURLCacheStoragePolicy, the NSURLCacheStorageAllowed constant is
>   always treated as NSURLCacheStorageAllowedInMemoryOnly and there is no
>   way to force it back, the code is certainly gone on this platform. For
>   whatever reason Apple removed this feature, you may be interested by
>   having on-disk HTTP request caching in your application. SDURLCache
>   gives back this feature to this iPhone OS for you.